# Using TailwindCSS in NX library

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, nomachine-nx

I created NX library for custom components with React and TailwindCSS.

It has basic NX rollup setup.

I tried to add custom colors to my `tailwind.config.js` like this:

```
const { createGlobPatternsForDependencies } = require('@nrwl/react/tailwind');
const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  content: [
    join(__dirname, 'src/**/!(*.stories|*.spec).{ts,tsx,html}'),
    ...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'black-1': `#123`,
      },

    },
  }
  plugins: [],
};
```

`postcss.config.js`

```
const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {
      config: join(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.js'),
    },
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

When I'm using custom color to style components, my library throws (on build)

```
 bg-black-1 was not found
```

When I try to use components from this library in nx application, it also throws an error and application is broken.
However, when I'm adding colors that are used in library to tailwind config in my application, everything works perfectly fine.

I need this library to be separated and works without changing application config.

Comment: Hello, could you solve it in the meantime?